# Why would I get Class must not be null exception?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to update a column in a table called PartnerPIDInfo,
with the following piece of code :

```
private HashMap<String, String> insertPartnerPIDInfoEntries(String 
partnerId, String environment, List<PartnerPidEntity> partnerPidInfoEntries, 
String user) {
    HashMap<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (PartnerPidEntity partnerPidInfoEntry : partnerPidInfoEntries) {
        logger.info("PartnerPidEntity entry:{}", partnerPidInfoEntry);
        //String key = partnerPidInfoEntry.getPartnerId() +"|"+ 
       partnerPidInfoEntry.getPID();
        partnerPidInfoEntry.setPartnerId(partnerId);
        String key = partnerPidInfoEntry.getPartnerId()+"|"+ 
        partnerPidInfoEntry.getBannerOMSPid();
        logger.info("PartnerPidEntity Key:" + key);
        try {
            partnerPidInfoEntry.fillDefaultField();
            omsdbReadWriteWrapper.insertPartnerPidInfoEntry(environment, 
            partnerPidInfoEntry);
            resultMap.put(key,"Success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception writing into PartnerPidEntity:" + 
             e.getMessage());
            resultMap.put(key,"Failed");
        }
    }
    return resultMap;
}
```

- **PartnerPidEntity class :**

  ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "dbo.PartnerPIDInfo", schema = "", catalog = "Coupons")
   public class PartnerPidEntity implements Serializable{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


   private String partnerId;
   private Integer bannerPid;
   private Timestamp createDate;
   private Boolean isActive;

  @Id
   @Column(name = "PartnerId", nullable = false, length = 64)
   public String getPartnerId() {
   return partnerId;
    }

   public void setPartnerId(String partnerId) {
   partnerId = partnerId;
   }

  @Id
   @Column(name = "PID", nullable = false, length = 20)
   public Integer getBannerOMSPid() {
   return bannerPid;
    }

   public void setBannerOMSPid(Integer bannerPid) {
   this.bannerPid = bannerPid;
   }

   @Basic
   @Column(name = "CreateDate", nullable = false, length = 20)
   public java.sql.Timestamp getCreateDate() {
   return createDate;
   }

   public void setCreateDate(java.sql.Timestamp createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
    }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "IsActive", nullable = false,  length = 10)
   public Boolean getIsActive() {
  return isActive;
  }

   public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
     this.isActive = isActive;
    }
   public PartnerPidEntity fillDefaultField(){
  this.createDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
  return this;
  }
  }
  ```

At line partnerPidInfoRepo.save(partnerPIDInfoEntity) ; 
I end up getting class must not be null exception.
Also adding the schema of PartnerPidInfo table :

```
TABLE "PartnerPIDInfo" (
"PartnerId" VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
"PID" INT NOT NULL,
"CreateDate" DATETIME NOT NULL,
"IsActive" BIT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("PartnerId", "PID")
)
```

**Exception log :**

```
 PartnerPidInfo: 
 [com.test.jaservice.entity.PartnerPidEntity@3f7bf0eb]
 [INFO] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:424[PDT] 
 com.test.jaservice.service.partnermanagement.ModifyPartnerServiceImpl 
 modifyPartnerDetailes - PartnerPidInfo: 
[com.quotient.jaservice.entity.PartnerPidEntity@3f7bf0eb]
[INFO] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:425[PDT] 
com.test.jaservice.service.partnermanagement.ModifyPartnerServiceImpl 
insertPartnerPIDInfoEntries - PartnerPidInfo
entry:com.test.jarvisservice.entity.PartnerPidEntity@3f7bf0eb
 [INFO] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:425[PDT] 
com.test.jaservice.service.partnermanagement.ModifyPartnerServiceImpl 
insertPartnerPIDInfoEntries - PartnerPidInfo Key:2ae444f9-b0c6-4714-bfba- 
6120b8a8c6d9|24081
[INFO] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:426[PDT] 
com.test.jaservice.relational.dao.core.DataSourceAspect beforeOMSDB - 
DataSourceAspect invoked
[INFO] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:427[PDT] 
com.test.jaservice.relational.dao.core.DataSourceAspect setDaoContext - 
Environment : DEV
[INFO] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:438[PDT] 
com.test.jaservice.relational.dao.core.ReadWriteAspect before - 
ReadWrite Aspect invoked
[INFO] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:440[PDT] 
com.test.jaservice.relational.dao.core.ReadWriteAspect before - Setting 
read and write access to mariaDB
[INFO] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:440[PDT] 
[INFO] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:441[PDT] 
com.test.jaservice.relational.dao.core.DataSourceRouter 
determineCurrentLookupKey - Read write Environment name: OMSDBDEVW
[ERROR] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:827[PDT]
com.test.jaservice.service.partnermanagement.ModifyPartnerServiceImpl 
insertPartnerPIDInfoEntries - Exception writing into PartnerPidInfo:Class 
must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Class must not be null
[INFO] 29 08 2018 01:35:01:838[PDT]
com.test.jaservice.rest.controllers.partnermanagement.
ModifyPartnerController modifyPartnerDetailsPOST - Modify Partner was 
Successfull : {2ae444f9-b0c6-4714-bfba-6120b8a8c6d9|24081=Failed}
```

**PartnerPIDEntity**

```
public interface PartnerPIDInfoRepo extends 
 BaseRepository<PartnerPidEntity,String> {

@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Query(value="select * from dbo.PartnerPIDInfo where PartnerId = ? 
  1",nativeQuery=true)
List<PartnerPidEntity> findAllPartnerPidInfoEntriesByPartnerId(String 
 partnerId);
}
```

**OMSDBReadWriteWrapper :**

```
 @Service
 public class OMSDBReadWriteWrapper {

@Autowired
private PartnerPIDInfoRepo partnerPidInfoRepo;

public List<PartnerPidInfo> getPartnerPIDInfoEntries(String environment, 
 String partnerId){
    List<PartnerPidEntity> partnerPIDInfoEntities = 
 partnerPidInfoRepo.findAllPartnerPidInfoEntriesByPartnerId(partnerId);
    return mapPartnerPIDInfoEntity(partnerPIDInfoEntities);
  }

 public void insertPartnerPidInfoEntry(String environment, PartnerPidEntity 
 partnerPIDInfoEntity){
    partnerPidInfoRepo.save(partnerPIDInfoEntity);
   }
  }
```

Please help me resolve this.
Thanks

Comment: Äff the complete stacktrace please

Comment: Please provide the exception details

Comment: Where is id field in your PartnerPidEntity?

Comment: That is not the id I am asking about the composite primary key of PartnerPidEntity?

Comment: Sorry, had messed that up while editing. Have added the proper entity class.

Comment: Still I couldn't figure out the issue.

Comment: The complete stacktrace is required. The information in the one you pasted is equivalent to "Error happened".

Comment: Can you add `PartnerPidInfoRepo` class and it's usage in `omsdbReadWriteWrapper`?

Comment: Added Repo and wrapper class.